# Flash Builder - arranging RadioButtonGroup horizontally - possible?

Tags: apache-flex, radio-button, flash-builder

Normally, RadioButtonGroup is aligned vertically like this:

```
O option 1
O option 2
O option 3
```

But I want this:

```
O option 1   O option 2   O option 3
```

Which property should I look for in Flash Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use horizontal layout within a group:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:RadioButton groupName="a"
                   label="one" />
    <s:RadioButton groupName="a"
                   label="two" />
    <s:RadioButton groupName="a"
                   label="three" />
</s:Group>
```

to produce:

[image: horizontal-radio-buttons]

Comment: Alternatively, drag and drop the RadioButtonGroup into HGroup.